# Help with Blender not "Honoring" Seams

Tags: texturing, uv

I clearly have a seam marked but blender is not "honoring" the seam in the UV's. Is there a setting somewhere I could be missing? Here is some picks, any help would be appreciated!
[image]
[image]

You an see the selected face, I would have thought the UV's would be spilt along the edge I highlighted in orange. I was looking for a way to manually split them but couldn't find it.

Comment: I'm not sure from those cropped pictures how blender is not 'honouring' the seams. Can you be more exact in which seams you think are being ignored? You can use the [edit] link below your question to add more information to your question if you need to.

Comment: Have you tries selecting everything in edit mode and hitting "Remove Doubles"

Comment: Can you upload the .blend file using [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so we can check it out?

Comment: Do you have duplicate verts around the loop that make another edge holding it together.